# Only calculate when finished entering week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I needed help generating a formula week wise. My goal is to have the First Contact (FC) and Follow-up (FU) calculated from Wednesday of a week to the Tuesday of next week by looking at the dates. So, in this case on cell M10 the FC should be 5 and on cell N10 the FU should be 3 and then again it would calculate for the next week from Wednesday until Tuesday so on M16 it should calculate FC as 1 and on N16 the FU as 4.
I need to continuously record data for further weeks therefore need a formula which could do so. Would a SUMIF be a good option here?

Currently I have the following formulas:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"First Contact") which calculates 6
=COUNTIF(A:A,"Follow-up") which calculates 7
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Formula in cell C2:

```
=IF(A2<>"";"";COUNTIFS(A:A;"First Contact";B:B;"<="&B1;B:B;">="&B1-6))
```

Formula in D2:

```
=IF(A2<>"";"";COUNTIFS(A:A;"Follow_up";B:B;"<="&B1;B:B;">="&B1-6))
```

Drag to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is sorted you could use the following:

In `M10` use: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A10,"First Contact")-SUM(M$1:M9)`

And in `N10` use: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A10,"Follow-up")-SUM(N$1:N9)`

And since your results show in an empty row, if you want a draggable solution, wrap it in IF like this: `=IF($A10="",COUNTIF($A$1:$A10,"FC")-SUM(M$1:M9),"")`

The `$` in the range reference for column letter and row number will lock the position if you drag the formula or copy it and paste it elsewhere.